# How to install Unirest without composer PHP?

Tags: java, unirest

I followed instructions on Github, still I am getting this error

> Class Unirest Not found

I followed this link https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php

Comment: So on that page you've got an "install from source" section. Have you followed that?